# t-test to compare weighted means

Tags: regression, t-test, inference, weighted-regression

I have an unbalanced panel of paired differences. That is, my panel consists of 100 firm time series of paired differences with varying length. I have tested wether the unweighted mean is different from zero by estimating an intercept only regression model. I used standard errors clustered at the firm-level to account for firm-level autocorrelation.

I now want to repeat this test for the mean weighted by firms, i.e. the mean which is equally influenced by each firm, irrespective of the number of observations per firm. Is this possible? If so, how exactly?